# ListView won't display InsertItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a `ListView` inside of an `AccordionPane` with an "Add Record" button. When I click the "Add Record" button, the `InsertItemTemplate` does not appear. Strangely, if I click the button a second time, it does appear. I've tried a number of things like adding `CommandName="InitInsert"` or `CommandName="Insert"` to the button, taking the `ListView` out of the `Accordion` that it's inside of, taking the "Insert" button out of the `ListView` then out of the `Accordion`, all to no avail. Is there something obvious that I'm missing? What am I doing wrong?

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="List1"  
    OnItemDataBound="List1_ItemDataBound"
    OnItemCommand="List1_ItemCommand"
    OnItemEditing="List1_ItemEditing"
    OnItemUpdating="List1_ItemUpdating"
    OnItemCanceling="List1_ItemCancelling"
    OnItemDeleting="List1_ItemDeleting"
    OnItemInserting="List1_ItemInserting"
    OnSorting="List1_Sorting">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="BtnCmpnyId" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="CmpnyId" Text="Company Code" /></th>
        ... more columns ...
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr><td colspan="7" style="text-align: center;">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="BtnAddRecord" Text="Add Record" OnClick="BtnAddRecord_Click" />
        </td></tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>

<InsertItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenID" Value="-1" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextCmpnyId" Text='<%# Eval("CmpnyId") %>' MaxLength="6" Width="50" />
        </td>

        ... more fields ...
    </tr>
</InsertItemTemplate>

... other templates ...
</asp:ListView>
```

In my code behind:

```
protected void BtnAddRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List1.EditIndex = -1;
    List1.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.LastItem;
    //Button button = (Button)List1.Controls[0].FindControl("BtnAddRecord");
    //button.Visible = false;
}

// ItemCommand() is an empty shell for now...
protected void List1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName.ToLower())
    {
        case "sort":
            break;

        case "edit":
            break;

        case "insert":
            break;

        case "update":
            break;

        case "cancel":
            break;

        case "delete":
            break;
    }
```

Comment: What's inside your OnItemInserting,OnItemXXXing,etc events. The code works without those events

Comment: @codingbiz - The only one that gets hit when I click the button is ItemCommand(), which I've added above.

Comment: Your code still works and `commandName == ""` - an empty string. Put a break point in each of the event handler and debug your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to rebind the ListView when you change the position, because the template building process is driven off binding.  Not 100% sure...

Comment: I am. See the second line of BtnAddRecord_Click() in my code-behind. I'll read the article now to see if there's something I can gather from it.

Comment: @BobKaufman sorry, missed that.  Completely changed my answer.

Comment: Holy cow that worked! And as far as why, it makes no sense to me whatsoever!